# How to get fix a bug where it dont shows any values in Select, I can click and it fetches the last object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, menuitem

**UPDATE** 
No real solution was found. Solved by using Context to send information  instead of sending all the information through Components.

---

I've made a list of items in Select that shows in a form. But the Select wont show any of the them. If i click the list it will show the last value in the Select box.

I tried rebuilding it in a clean reactjs script and it ran just fine. Might be something I've forgotten that I cant figure out.

I've used dummy versions from the Material-ui website, but get the same error.
I've also tried to build a clean version of just the template form, and it ran just fine. So the code should be correct.

```
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="listOfInformation">
         List of Information
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
         value={listOfInformation}
         name='List of Information'
         onChange={this.handleChange('listOfInformation')}
    >
         {categories.map(category => 
              <MenuItem 
                   open={open} 
                   key={category} 
                   value={category}
              >
                   {category}
                   {console.log("Test ", category)}
              </MenuItem>
         )}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

This is located inside my Form. My Form also have TextFields that works just fine. I've called the component in App.js to make sure I didnt do anything wrong before, it got the same error.

The popup dosent show that good. It should show the entire list of Information

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces the issue. It is difficult to help without seeing more of the code involved (e.g. how do you set `categories`).

Comment: Thanks, but I figured the problem out. Or atleast I managed to solve it by using context to pass information. I don't think I could write code to get the same bug. Since the problem was how I handled the sending through Components. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happend. I think I had some errors with how i handled my values while sending them through Components (was nested 4 deep). I've changed my handling to use context instead. This solved this bug. I think It wasn't grabbing correct value.

The solution for me was to use context instead to handle all my values. I used this solution because I thought Redux or similar solutions would be to much, but needed context because I was passing way to much information.